# Showing that $B_j$ is a cauchy sequence with respect to the operator norm

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given A $\in$ $L( \mathbb{R}^n ) $ , show that $B_j$ is a cauchy sequence with respect to the operator norm where $$B_j = \sum_{r=0}^{j} \frac{A^r}{r!} $$

So far I have gotten that $|| B_m - B_n|| = || \displaystyle\sum_{r=n+1}^{m} \frac{A^r}{r!}||$ $$ \leq \sum_{r=n+1}^{m} \frac{1}{r!} ||A||^r $$

I am confused where to go from here as most examples include the fact that $||A|| \leq 1$ and/or don't include $r!$ in $B_j$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further continue from your work with
$$\|B_m - B_n\| \le \sum_{r=n+1}^\infty \frac{\|A\|^r}{r!}.$$
The right-hand side converges to zero as $n \to \infty$ because the series $\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{\|A\|^r}{r!} = e^{\|A\|}$ is convergent. Thus you have shown $(B_n)$ is Cauchy.